# Storing credit card information in session to prepolulate the info for better user experience

Tags: php, session

I am using PHP

I am planning to store the credit card info in the session and prepopulate it if user navigates to other pages and comes back.

For ex: I have cart -> payment -> order review

User adds credit card info in the payment page and navigates to order review

Now, the user decides to go back to cart/product pages and comes back to payment page.

I am thinking of prepoluating the credit card info which the the user just entered because, this way user doesn't need to add the credit card info again.

Is it a good practice to

1. store in session and
2. prepoluate

the credit card info which the the user just entered?

Comment: There are PCI compliance issues at play here. Is your server PCI compliant?

Comment: yes, the server is PCI compliant

Comment: Is going to be not compliant by the time you finish this task.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is bad practice to store credit card info in this way. It will lead to security issues.

I would think that the most common use case is to visit the payment page exactly once. If a user navigates away from the payment page and then returns to it, they won't expect the card details to be pre-populated as no other site offers this feature.

I would recommend just dropping this feature entirely, it doesn't seem worth the effort. But if you are convinced you need it then have a look at how Amazon does it.